# setting rowstyle in datagrid, silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, coding-style

I am trying to change the rowstyle for a datagrid to change the background color when a row is selected(not the row background but the color of the selection rectangle, which by default is a bit too shiny for my application). However the behaviour i'm seeing on applying to style to the grid is that all the rows are getting shrinked together like a folded venetian blind. This is the style that i have written:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <sdk:DataGrid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">                                       
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                                                To="Red" />                                            
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here? tbh I havn't really understood how the visual states work and kind of just shooting in the dark.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the template for the DataGrid ([check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)) the background color (that blue) is hard coded in the template. When the row is selected all that happens is that a rectangle becomes visible (Opacity=1). Sadly have to say that you have to re-template the whole DataGridRow... in the provided link you'll find all you might need for this.

In the template look for some code like this:
`<Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9"/>`

Comment: That link was very useful. I took the entire control template for the datagridrow and changed the parts related to Normal selected state and it seems to be working fine. Thank you.